# How to re-calculate height with an equal columns script

Tags: jquery, css

http://www.indigoeastend.com/live-entertainment.html

I have a page, listed above, which has accordion boxes which can break the layout when opened. In particular the last one. I use the following script to get the columns equal:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".equal_heights").equalHeights();
});

(function($) {
    $.fn.equalHeights = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {
        tallest = (minHeight) ? minHeight : 0;
        this.each(function() {
            if($(this).height() > tallest) {
                tallest = $(this).height();
            }
        });
        if((maxHeight) && tallest > maxHeight) tallest = maxHeight;
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).height(tallest).css("overflow","visible");
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

How can I get both columns to resize when the box is broken. I was experimenting with innerheight but that wasn't working. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you've chosen to go with JavaScript for the purpose of creating equal height columns when there are pure CSS options available?

Comment: as far as i know there isnt really any good/true equal height css options available...

Comment: @cimmanon: because it's *painful* in pure CSS, probably.

Comment: Why is everyone so scared of `table` these days? Honestly, if it were me, I'd have put that entire layout in table rows with `vertical-align: top;` thus maintaining the exact same layout you have  but with equal column heights defined by tallest cell content. Would be a TON easier than JS'ing your way into a corner

Comment: @SpYk3HH And how well does that translate to mobile devices?  Not to mention that using tables that way is awful for accessibility reasons.

Comment: I've done it for 2 programs being used in docs offices on both android and ipad tablets. seems to be working fine ...

Comment: If the accordion box was a `div/section/etc` element that was floated left or right, and properly cleared, I don't think this would break your layout.

Comment: Using tables is definitely bad for layout and structure. It's also bad for load times as it needs to calculate width and height out on initial load and also on resize. I realize that the event calendar is in table format (not my choice, the component developers') but my issue is not with the structure at all.

It was set up in a specific way and it needs to remain in that structure. What I am asking about is how to retrigger the equal height when it breaks the bottom border of MiddleCol2.

Comment: Does anyone have any insight into how to trigger the equal heights function again on a height change on MiddleCol2? I appreciate the css vs. tables debate but it's really not relevant to the issue at hand. It's a jQuery problem with what I believe will end up being a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself a lot of trouble by just using CSS to get yourself equal height columns.  The simplest technique is to change the display property of your element to table-cell:

http://tinker.io/ae84b

```css
.main {
    display: table; /* optional */
}

.main article, .main aside {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <article>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </article>

    <aside>
        I'm the aside!
    </aside>
</div>
```

This works with an unlimited number of "columns", as long as they're adjacent and table-cell.  Because floats aren't used, there's no need to clear them.  The other advantage is that because it is pure CSS, you can hide your 2-column layout from narrow devices via media queries.